# How to keep certain divs after .html(data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a `div` like this:

```
<div id = "foo" style = "display: grid">
    <div id = "bar"> keep me! </div>
</div>
```

and using JQuery' `.html(data)` like this:

```
$('#foo').html(data);
```

using an AJAX call and retreiving data, it would overwrite `#bar`. How would I prevent this? After I make another AJAX call, I would like to keep `#bar` but not the other elements that would've been inserted by the previous AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You should store `bar` into a variable, call your `ajax` and then append your `data` with the `bar`

```
var bar = $('#bar')[0].outerHTML;
// Call ajax
// In Response do the following
data += bar; // added bar after response
// OR
data = bar + data; // added bar before response
// Then write to your div
$('#foo').html(data);
// Or
$('#foo').empty().append(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as bellow:

```
<div id = "foo" style = "display: grid">
    <div id = "bar"> keep me! </div>
    <div id="nothing"></div>
</div>
```

Then use prepend method to insert new content before nothing ID.

```
$('#nothing').prepend(data);
```

Comment: But if I make another AJAX call, wouldn't that keep appending and not get rid of the old data?

Comment: Thanks, but how would I get rid of it once I'm done with it? I would want to remove everything but `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after` to add a sibiling element - `$('#bar').after(data);`
You can read more about `after` and `insertAfter` [here](https://api.jquery.com/after/)